# Use of @StateObject in Document-based SwiftUI application: getting instances instead of references

Tags: swift, swiftui, observedobject, document-based

I am trying to use a @Stateobject in my document as source of truth for the dataModel behind the document. However, it seems I am doing something wrong as I appear to get different instances for the document and the content view, which is in line with the warnings I am receiving: `Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time.`

Can anybody help? I am pretty sure this has a very simple fix...

Here is the code:

Observed Object:

```
class TestObject:ObservableObject{
    @Published var text: String
    init(){
        text = "initString"
    }
}
```

App:

```
@main
struct FileOpen5App: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: FileOpen5Document()) { file in
            ContentView(document: file.$document, obj: file.document.docObject) /// instance warning
        }
    }
}
```

Document (partial):

```
struct FileOpen5Document: FileDocument {
    //var text: String
    @StateObject var docObject = TestObject()

    init() {
        docObject.text = "DocText" /// instance warning
    }
...
```

ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: FileOpen5Document
    @ObservedObject var obj: TestObject
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(obj.text)
    }
}
'''
```

Comment: As the warning alludes to, `@StateObject` is for use inside a `View` -- you're trying to own it inside a `FileDocument`. What happens if you just remove the property wrapper?

Comment: I originally designed it to have the data object directly as a variable of the document, however, I get problems if I re-shape the data in response to user input  as the View will hit it and cause out-of-bounds errors etc. I thought putting it into a observable object, I can prevent those errors (object will change notifications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@StateObject` is just for Views, try [ReferenceFileDocument](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/referencefiledocument) but before you resort to using classes I highly recommend figuring out if you can stick to structs because Swift and SwiftUI work best with value types. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing_between_structures_and_classes